# EventBridge Scheduler fails on ECS RunTask with Fargate launch type

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

When defining the Compute Options on a RunTask call with: Launch type - "FARGATE", Platform Version: "1.4.0" - it seems that only the Platform Version is passed onto the "requestParameters" thus triggering the following error message: "The platform version must be null when specifying an EC2 launch type."

Screenshot from Eventbridge Scheduler:
[image]

Screenshot from the output in CloudTrail:
[image]

Comment: I got the same issue and I opened a case in aws support, they told me that they're working to solve this issue

Comment: I just got confirmation from the aws team, the fix is deployed, can you check (specifically us-east-2)